# Debian shared library setup

Tags: package-management, shared-library, deb

I have a Debian package for a shared library.
Lets assume the lib is called threadx.
And I have the version 0.0.1 installed.
So this package contains:

```
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libthreadx.so.0.0.1
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libthreadx.so.0 # symlink to libthreadx.so.0.0.1
```

If I want to upgrade now to 0.0.2 the package will contain:

```
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libthreadx.so.0.0.2
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libthreadx.so.0 # symlink to libthreadx.so.0.0.2
```

Which conflicts because `/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libthreadx.so.0` is the same file.
The error message is

```
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-SwpeYD/01-libthreadx0.0.2_0.0.2_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libthreadx.so.0', which is also in package libthreadx0.0.1:i386 0.0.1
```

I want to be able to install both packages (`libthreadx0.0.1` and `libthreadx0.0.2`) in parallel, and have the symlink point to the latest library.

And I am unable to find actual advice how to configure/package this that this works.
There is this thread talking about it but not telling any details:

> Actually, you can install multiple versions of a shared library if it's done properly.

[Why can't I install multiple versions of a shared library?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209710/why-cant-i-install-multiple-versions-of-a-shared-library)

And the debian manual is also very obscure to me so either the information on how to do this is not there or i don't understand it. https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-sharedlibs.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the presence of the full version in the package name: `libthreadx0.0.2` and `libthreadx0.0.1`. When you install the former, `dpkg` doesn’t consider it to be an upgrade to the latter, but a new package installed alongside it. As a result, `dpkg` won’t handle “replaced” files for you automatically, you have to provide additional information to help it do so.

In theory, library package names are supposed to reflect the library’s soname, `libthreadx.so.0` in this case; so the library package should be `libthreadx0`, with an appropriate version number after the underscore: `libthreadx0_0.0.1-1_i386.deb`, `libthreadx0_0.0.2-1_i386.deb`. But as you note, this doesn’t allow parallel installation.

Since you want to allow parallel installation, you have to allow packages containing later versions of the library to replace the symlink in earlier packages: you can do this by adding [a `Replaces` stanza](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html#s-replaces) in the package’s control file, *e.g.* in this instance, in `libthreadx0.0.2`’s control file,

```
Replaces: libthreadx0.0.1
```

This doesn’t mean that `libthreadx0.0.2` entirely replaces `libthreadx0.0.1`, but it allows it to provide conflicting files. When `libthreadx0.0.2` is installed, its symlink will replace `libthreadx0.0.1`’s.

Technically, since this changes the symlink, it “breaks” (in `dpkg` terminology) the `libthreadx0.0.1` package — or rather, it breaks packages relying on `libthreadx0.0.1`, since they will no longer find the right library through the symlink formerly provided by `libthreadx0.0.1`. This would typically be declared using a `Breaks` stanza as well, but this isn’t appropriate here since you want to keep `libthreadx0.0.1`.

This will also result in a broken setup if the user installs `libthreadx0.0.1`, installs `libthreadx0.0.2`, then removes `libthreadx0.0.2`, expecting `libthreadx0.0.1` to be used again: the symlink won’t be restored.

The fact that your soname is the same in both libraries suggests that they aren’t really *usable* in parallel in the first place, but that’s a concern for another discussion.